# scheduling a mysql event to run on saturday and Thursday

Tags: mysql, events

I want to create a mysql event to run only on Saturday and Thursday.

Is it possible to define the days in event itself?

I have an idea to run the scheduler everyday and if it is thursday or saturday, then the process will continue or else it will exit the scheduler without doing anything.

Comment: Hello and welcome back to stackoverflow. I've edited your question to remove the greetings as is SO you will primarily say "thank you" by voting / accepting answers. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for the details.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to check the current day, you will probably have to create two events, repeating `EVERY 7 DAY`

```
CREATE EVENT myevent_saturday
    ON NOW() + INTERVAL xxx DAY -- days till next saturday
      EVERY 7 DAY
    DO
      -- this and that
```

---

That said, as of myself I would push to an event firing every day and checking the current [`DAYOFWEEK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek)...

Answer (score 0):

Also you will need to edit the Event Scheduler status in the config file. 
And to make sure it's running, run this:

```
SHOW EVENTS;
```